# how to change the position of arrow in actionbar

Tags: android

I'm developing a `slide menu` in the action bar.

I downloaded slide menu source code from GitHub, but I can't change the position of the action bar icon.

The action bar is positioned to the `left` and I want to place it on the `right.`

How would you recommend I go about changing `*action bar icon(ex.arrow icom)*`?

Answer (score 0):

You need your slide menu to be opened from right side

Then you should do somtthing like this in your code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer, setting gravity to "end" means "right" but preferabbly use "end"-->
<ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"       
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

When you change your xml like this, i think your sliding menu will open/close from Right side

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. however.What i wanna.  I 'm not exechange position listview but exechange to the right  position of arrow icon. Do you know how to move to the right position of a arrow icon.